# How to remove "?" from python data frame field

Tags: python

I have a python dataframe,named `data`. In this data frame one field is `price` with data type `object`.
The data frame contains missing value in different fields & missing values are `"?"`. I want to replace that missing value. I thought to replace `"?"` by `"NaN"` & then apply `fillna()`. So I wrote this code

```
data.replace('?','NaN')
```

But after executing this code,I'm still getting "?" while I'm writing below line

```
data['price'].max()
```

Can you suggest me what is the correct way? i'm using python 3.6 on Windows 10

Comment: Could sign "?" mean None value?

Comment: Try `np.nan` instead of the string `NaN` that you're using. Also be sure to either asign to a new DataFrame or set `inplace=True`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `np.nan`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.DataFrame({"price": ["?", "Hello", "?", "World"]})
data["price"].replace('?',np.nan, inplace=True)
print(data.fillna(0))
```

**Output:**

```
   price
0      0
1  Hello
2      0
3  World
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `inplace=True` to keep changes in your original dataframe.

```
data.replace('?','NaN', inplace=True)
```